Extract difference between composite foreground+background image, and standalone image of just the background?
Using Photoshop, I have an image A depicting a magic scroll, inscribed with a spell and a bunch of sparkly visual effects in front.
I also have an image B of the same magic scroll, but without the spell or effects. It is not a perfect match, but somewhat close.
Can I somehow use the separate "scroll" image to grab the difference between image A and B, to extract just the "spell and visual effects" part, standalone, on a transparent background?
What techniques could I use for this?

Can you share the image you want to extract?  It's hard to be specific without seeing anything. But I wouldn't go down the route you suggest. Making a mask would probably be your best bet.

A method that gave me some success is:

Open the composite image
Add the background image over it as a layer
Set that layer to "Subtract"
Copy the resulting image as "Merged" and apply it where needed with "Linear Dodge"

But this is probably not optimal, and the "linear dodge" result wouldn't be for everyone, too, so I don't consider it a real answer.
It seems to depend on the foreground being brighter than the background, as well.
